# Is it possible to make httprequest from Azure cosmos db?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to learn Azure Cosmos Db. I've read the document. 
As far as I see, we can create .Net/NodeJs/Java applications, and get/insert/update data in the Cosmos Db.

However, I'm not clear whether we can make a http request from JavaScript/JQuery/etc..

to fetch data: 
does cosmos db provide only .net/java/nodejs/phyton, or we can make a request using any software language?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make HTTP requests to Cosmos DB resources using JavaScript/jQuery simply because in order for you to do that, you have to enable CORS on Cosmos DB which is currently not supported. Any other higher level languages, you can do that.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I haven't tried yet but according to the below document, it looks that possible. Do you think that it is not enough?  http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js/

Comment: Even I have not tried it but I remember asking a similar question to Cosmos DB team long time back about their JavaScript SDK and they told me that it is for building Windows 8 applications. Please do give it a try and let us know. I may be wrong here.

Comment: @GauravMantri I will try and edit my question later. Thanks for your interesting.

Comment: @GauravMantri I achieved to make an http request. I have answered my question. You can make a http request applying the steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cosmos exposes a REST API, so you can access with anything capable of creating HTTP requests. Here’s the API documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/

Comment: Hey.. this looks what I need. I'm gonna look at this. Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my question. I tried to make an http request from Azure Cosmos DB and I did.

There is only one crucial step that you need to create an auth code for each request. You can create the auth code by reading below page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN

This is the detailed document for using Cosmos DB Rest API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/restful-interactions-with-documentdb-resources

I hope this would be helpful.